# Google Drive crashes on start

Tags: nexus-4, google-drive

I has happened 4 times now, I change some setting, delete the sheet open in the app from the PC, create a wrong function, and from then on, the Google Drive app crashes on start. I can not close the faulty document, so it keeps happening until I remove the application. You would think a restart of the phone should help, but it does not.

Is there a setting somewhere that lets me open the list instead of the most recent document?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the data (via App Manager) for the Google Drive app? See if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing Cache is not enough, however clearing the Data solved the problem. Of course then you have to set offline availability of your documents again.